# Json decoding error - strange characters apprearing on json.loads() instead of text

Tags: python, json

I am trying to make an API call to http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/badges/name

My code snippet -

```
url = 'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/badges/name'
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = f.read()
jsonobj = json.loads(content)
print jsonobj
```

This gives me the error - 
    ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

When I tried http://jsonviewer.stack.hu  to load the json object from the above URL, it showed me garbled characters. You can see the output here - http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/badges/name

The text is displayed normally in the browser window if you go to http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/badges/name

I tried adding UTF-8 encoding -

```
jsonobj = json.loads(content, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage the returned information is gzipped.  You will have to unzip the binary data to get the actual JSON.  You can do this with the `gzip` and `StringIO` modules:

```
url = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/badges/name')
zippedContents = url.read()
sio = StringIO.StringIO(zippedContents)
gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=sio)
print gz.read()
```